# TypeError: filteredCharacters.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

, Soy un programador junior-novato en React.JS y tengo un error con este código, y espero que alguno de ustedes me pueda ayudar a encontrar la solución !

Lo que intento hacer con mi código es, llamar a una API,(específicamente la de rick and morty) luego lo que hago es que, como la data se esta guardando en mi variable Data, hice una función que esta haciendo un metodo filter de mi Data, para poder encontrar especificamente el nombre del personaje que estoy buscando, y esta función obviamente es para poder que mi barra de busqueda sirva, pero, lo que sucede, es que cuando hago console.log de mi variable Data, mi información de la API no me esta llegando, por lo tanto, tengo undefined y luego tengo errores con mi función .map (que se supone que me debería mapear los personajes que escriba en la barra de busqueda)

Este es mi archivo principal

```
import React, {
useState,
useEffect,
useRef,
useMemo,
useCallback
} from "react";

import "./Cards.css";

import loading from "../Images/loading.png";
import { FaCircle } from "react-icons/fa";
import SearchBar from "../components/Search";

const Cards = ({ styles }) => {
const [Data, setData] = useState([]);
const [number, setNumber] = useState(1);
const [Loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

const searchInput = useRef(null);
const [search, setSearch] = useState("");

// Search Bar

const handleSearch = () => {
  useCallback(() => {
    setSearch(searchInput.current.value);
  }, []);
};

const filteredCharacters = () => {
  useMemo(() => {
    Data.filter(person => {
      return person.status.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase());
    });
  }, []);
};

console.log(filteredCharacters());

// Fetching rick and morty's api

const url = `https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/?page=${number}`;

const handleData = () => {
  setNumber(number + 1);
  setLoading(!Loading);
};

const fetching = async () => {
  try {
    const res = await fetch(url);
    const data = await res.json();
    setLoading(!Loading);
    setData(Data.concat(data.results));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

useEffect(() => {
  fetching();
}, [number]);

if (Loading) {
  return (
    <div className={styles ? "Loading-black" : "Loading"}>
      <img src={loading} alt="" />
    </div>
  );
} else if (Data !== undefined) {
  return (
    <>
      {/* The Whole Data */}
      <div className={styles ? "Cards-container_black" : "Cards-container"}>
        {/* Search Bar */}

        <SearchBar
          styles={styles}
          search={search}
          searchInput={searchInput}
          handleSearch={handleSearch}
        />

        {filteredCharacters.map(character => {
          const {
            id,
            name,
            status,
            species,
            gender,
            origin,
            image
          } = character;
          return (
            <div className="Cards-container_character" key={id}>
              <div
                className="Character-img"
                style={{
                  background: `url(${image})`,
                  backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
                  backgroundSize: "cover",
                  maxWidth: "100%",
                  height: "auto"
                }}
              ></div>
              <div
                className={styles ? "Character-inf_black" : "Character-inf"}
              >
                <h2 className="Character-inf_title">{name}</h2>
                {status === "Alive" ? (
                  <p className="Character-inf_text">
                    {" "}
                    <FaCircle className="Status-alive" /> {status} - {species}{" "}
                  </p>
                ) : (
                  <p className="Character-inf_text">
                    {" "}
                    <FaCircle className="Status-dead" /> {status} - {species}{" "}
                  </p>
                )}

                <p className="Character-inf_text2">{gender}</p>
                <h2 className="Character-inf_title">Origin</h2>
                <p className="Character-inf_text2">{origin.name}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        })}
        <div className="More">
          <button onClick={handleData} className="More-button">
            More Data
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
};

export default Cards;
```

Este es mi archivo de mi barra de busqueda

```
import React from "react";

import "./Search.css";

const Search = ({ styles, search, handleSearch, searchInput }) => {
  return (
    <div className={styles ? "Search-black" : "Search"}>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Name Of The Character"
        maxLength="50"
        ref={searchInput}
        value={search}
        onChange={handleSearch}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Search;
```

Esta el la foto del error en el navegador

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Le he estado dando vueltas y no puedo encontrar la solución, siempre que modifico de alguna u otra manera para obtener el mismo resultado, me aparece otro tipo de errores y empeoro el progreso :(

Comment: El error es claro, tu estado filteredCharacters no es un array y por eso no tiene acceso a la función map. Te recomiendo que hagas uno console.log justo antes de renderizar con el map (puedes ponerlo así: {console.log(filteredCharacteres)} antes de {filteredCharacters.map(... Ahí podrás ver qué valor tiene exactamente ese estado.

Comment: Kilo_L, Muchisimas gracias por tomarte el tiempo de responder la pregunta, tiene sentido tu aclaración !

Comment: No obstante, obtengo un error de undefined, y se supone sino estoy mal, de que me debería de dar un array vacio ya que aún no escribo nada en la barra de navegación

Comment: no debiera ser `filteredCharacters().map`  ?

Comment: ffflabs, no amigo, ya lo solucione, gracias !